# What should be the value of the two constants C and N to prove this?

Tags: asymptotics

I am supposed to prove the following:

$n^{10} = O(2^{n/2}) $

So I proceed as follows:

There are $C > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such as for any $n \geqslant N$,
$$n^{10} \leqslant C 2^{n/2}$$

$\iff$ $\frac{n^{10}}{2^{n/2}} \leqslant C$

But then I am stuck with how to find the values of $N$ and  $C$, what should be the next step?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to determine $N$ and $C$? It is well-known that $n^\alpha=o(2^{\beta n})$ for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, and function which is $o(2^{\beta n})$ is *ipso facto* $O(2^{\beta n})$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. 
But I think our teacher wants us to find the Constant C and the value of N.

Comment: Yet, it should be obvious: a function $f$ is $o(g)$ if the ratio $f/g$ tends to $0$, and it is $O(g)$, roughly speaking, if the same ratio is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

First you notice that, when $n$ increases to $n+1$, the expression $n^{10}$ grows by the factor of $\frac{(n+1)^{10}}{n^{10}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{10}$, which is getting smaller as $n$ gets bigger. On the other hand, the expression $2^{n/2}$ grows by the constant factor $\sqrt{2}$.

This means that the second rate of growth will eventually overtake the first. Once $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{10}\lt\sqrt{2}$, the first expression will grow by the smaller factor than the second one, and so the *ratio* of the two $\frac{n^{10}}{2^{n/2}}$ will start to decrease.

This will happen when $1+\frac{1}{n}\lt\sqrt[20]{2}$, i.e. when $n>\frac{1}{\sqrt[20]{2}-1}$. You can take $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt[20]{2}-1}\right\rceil$ (which is the previous number "rounded up").

Now, as we know that, for $n\ge N$, the ratio $\frac{n^{10}}{2^{n/2}}$ will only decrease, take as $C$ the value of that ratio when $n=N$, i.e. take:

$$C=\frac{N^{10}}{2^{N/2}}$$

where $N$ has been calculated in the previous step. For $n\ge N$ we will have $\frac{n^{10}}{2^{n/2}}\le \frac{N^{10}}{2^{N/2}}=C$, i.e. $n^{10}\le C2^{n/2}$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(n)=\log \left(2^{-n/2} n^{10}\right)$$ its derivatives are
$$f'(n)=\frac{10}{n}-\frac{\log (2)}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(n)=-\frac{10}{n^2}\quad <0 \quad \forall n$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$n_*=\frac{20}{\log (2)}\sim 28.8539 \implies f(n_*)=-10 \left(1+\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{20}\right)\right)\sim 23.6225$$ and
$$e^{f(n_*)} \sim 1.81594\times 10^{10}$$